# Is accessing a class by a string possible in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a sql stored procedure that I run that returns a class name.  For example it returns "orange".  I have a class called "orange".  Is it possible to use that return string to access orange.GrabFiles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use System.Reflection to get the class which you need and invoke the method you want to call.

To do this you can iterate though all types of the assembly and pick the right one for you. If you have special names you can use attributes to link a specific type with a special name.

#### Search the type

```
// Type to find
String name = "orange";
// I assume you only use one assembly
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
// Iterate though all types
foreach (Type item in asm.GetTypes())
{
    if (item.Name == name)
    {
        return item;
    }
    else
    {
        // A class can have multiple SpecialNameAttributes, this is a attribute you have to create
        SpecialNameAttribute[] attributes = (SpecialNameAttribute[])item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SpecialNameAttribute));
        foreach (SpecialNameAttribute attribute in attributes)
        {
            if (attribute.Name == name) return item;
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

#### Invoke the method

With instance creation:

```
Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeFound);
typeFound.GetMethod("GrabFiles").Invoke(instance, ...);
```

Without instance:

```
typeFound.GetMethod("GrabFiles").Invoke(null, ...);
```

Comment: Cool, never used it before do you have a small sample?

Comment: @Mike I going to add a sample, give me a sec.

Comment: @Mike Did it help? Or did you found another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the namespace for "orange" is "fruits" you can do the following:

```
dynamic d = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("fruits.orange"));
d.GrabFiles();
```

Quite simple and straight-forward as long as you know what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few return values, all known at compile time, then it will be simpler to check the result and branch accordingly (using `switch` or a sequence of `if`s).

If you need more dynamic behaviour you can do `Type typeToCall = Type.GetType(typeName);` and then use [`typeToCall.InvokeMember(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bese341c.aspx).

Comment: One little side note: `switch` with strings are always converted into dictionaries ( `Dictionary<String, Int32>` with a switch on the value ), so you gain a better performance when using the dictionary direcly ( `Dictionary<String, Type>` ) instead of let the compiler do it.

Comment: @FelixK fair point, but the performance improvement you get from moving away from reflection is much more significant.